# Unable to deploy java based app on Openshift v3

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, jboss, openshift

I am trying to deploy JEE/mysql based application on openshift v3.

However, when I use 'exposed' URL(java-zeek.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com). I am getting a 404 error.

Following is my complete configuration:

```
zeek@zeek:~$ oc get all

NAME      TYPE      FROM      LATEST
bc/java   Source    Git       3

NAME            TYPE      FROM          STATUS     STARTED       DURATION
builds/java-3   Source    Git@85660aa   Complete   3 hours ago   55s

NAME      DOCKER REPO                    TAGS      UPDATED
is/java   172.30.148.65:5000/zeek/java   latest    3 hours ago

NAME       REVISION   DESIRED   CURRENT   TRIGGERED BY
dc/java    4          1         1         config,image(java:latest)
dc/mysql   1          1         1         config,image(mysql:5.7)

NAME         DESIRED   CURRENT   READY     AGE
rc/java-4    1         1         1         2h
rc/mysql-1   1         1         1         4h

NAME          HOST/PORT                                            PATH      SERVICES   PORT       TERMINATION   WILDCARD
routes/java   java-zeek.a3c1.starter-us-west-1.openshiftapps.com             java       8080-tcp                 None

NAME        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
svc/java    172.30.92.188    <none>        8080/TCP,8443/TCP,8778/TCP   3h
svc/mysql   172.30.217.149   <none>        3306/TCP                     4h

NAME               READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
po/java-4-sdkqh    1/1       Running   0          2h
po/mysql-1-23vnw   1/1       Running   0          4h
```

I see the ROOT.war has been generated but is placed at ./tmp/src/webapps/ (java pod) I tried to manually copy it to /deployments , still did not work for me.

PS: The build was successful and it honored all the dependencies from pom.xml

What is missing from my side?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue

Comment: Patrick, we just have 30 days to migrate :( ...Let me know for any breakthru plz. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to help anyone who encounters same kind of problem. This solution may not be what you are looking for but sure must be one of the things to check.

My pom.xml had some outputDirectory which once commented out helped openshift platform to move war to right location.

Works like charm

Answer (score 1):

I just hit `rebuild` today. All the process (fetching, buidling, deploying) went fine, as yesterday, but this time, the App is up and running!!! I guess it might had to do with a maintenance process..  In any case, problem solved !

By the way, congrats to the Openshift team. Deployment of an app is dead simple!

Comment: Thanks Patrick,  you gave me confidence enough to understand what was wrong with my configuration. My pom.xml had a specific outputDirectory which was ruining everything for me.

Comment: glad I could help in some way ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can load source code on github and build there